# "An Internet connection cannot be established" when using Motorola Device Manager

Tags: motorola

I picked up a Motorola Luge for some testing. I plugged it into my Mac and it launched Motorola Device Manager. The device manager appears to check for updates (I presume for both the program and the device, but I'm not sure either guess is correct).

Motorola Device Manager is failing with the error message *"An Internet connection cannot be established"*. Obviously, the Mac is online and the Internet connection works because I'm asking this question.

Similar questions provide disingenuous answers, like "make sure you have an internet connection". See, for example, [Why won't my Motorola Device Manager connect to the internet?](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/478005-why-won-t-my-motorola-device-manager-connect-internet.html).

How do I fix Motorola Device Manager? Or how do I troubleshoot it?

---

The error message appear below in the lower left hand corner.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the software is broken out of the box and it cannot be fixed. It's trying to connect to the host `www.mymotocast.com`, but it can't find the path or there is no server listening:

[image: wireshark analysis]

And:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.mymotocast.com:443
connect: Operation timed out
connect:errno=60

$ nslookup www.mymotocast.com
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.mymotocast.com
Address: 92.242.140.21

$ traceroute 92.242.140.21
traceroute to 92.242.140.21 (92.242.140.21), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  gateway (192.168.1.1)  0.666 ms  0.427 ms  0.406 ms
 2  l100.bltmmd-vfttp-32.verizon-gni.net (96.234.147.1)  5.970 ms  6.265 ms  6.653 ms
 3  g0-10-0-6.bltmmd-lcr-21.verizon-gni.net (130.81.217.20)  10.525 ms  16.128 ms  12.693 ms
 4  so-1-1-0-0.res-bb-rtr1.verizon-gni.net (130.81.199.2)  33.310 ms  16.435 ms
    ae4-0.res-bb-rtr2.verizon-gni.net (130.81.209.230)  19.951 ms
 5  0.ae3.br2.iad8.alter.net (152.63.38.117)  15.596 ms
    0.ae4.br2.iad8.alter.net (152.63.7.225)  16.676 ms
    0.ae3.br2.iad8.alter.net (152.63.38.117)  14.921 ms
 6  te0-1-0-14.ccr41.iad02.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.12.45)  13.116 ms  12.950 ms  14.240 ms
 7  be2113.mpd21.dca01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.6.170)  16.623 ms
    be2176.ccr21.dca01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.41.54)  19.256 ms
    be2177.ccr22.dca01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.41.206)  17.821 ms
 8  be2153.ccr42.ord01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.30.126)  38.219 ms
    be2152.ccr41.ord01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.30.122)  38.014 ms
    be2170.ccr41.atl01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.31.105)  34.687 ms
 9  be2157.ccr22.mci01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.6.117)  60.086 ms
    be2173.ccr22.iah01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.29.118)  57.216 ms
    be2156.ccr21.mci01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.6.85)  61.500 ms
10  be2065.ccr21.lax01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.5.66)  75.636 ms
    be2066.ccr22.lax01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.7.54)  75.899 ms
    be2065.ccr21.lax01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.5.66)  78.758 ms
11  be2161.ccr22.sjc01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.27.170)  86.520 ms
    be2165.ccr22.sjc01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.28.66)  83.322 ms
    be2164.ccr21.sjc01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.28.34)  90.599 ms
12  be2063.rcr21.b001848-1.sjc01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.1.162)  87.420 ms
    be2095.rcr21.b001848-1.sjc01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.3.138)  90.178 ms  92.828 ms
13  as26803.xe-2-0-3.ar1.sjc2.us.as4436.gtt.net (69.22.143.162)  89.610 ms  89.776 ms  79.943 ms
14  sanjose2.barefruit.co.uk (66.201.32.134)  77.673 ms  79.710 ms  82.876 ms
15  * * *
...
```